# How can i create a user without role authenticated user role

Tags: users

I am creating some users programaticaly with role "staff". I don't want them as my authenticated user. I created them for a particular purpose. I don't want any permissions which are assigned to authenticated users for this role.

```
 $userinfo = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'init' => $mail,
            'mail' => $mail,
            'pass' => $pass,
            'status' => 1,
            'roles' => array(               
             9 => 'staff',
            ),                
            );                
            $account = user_save(null, $userinfo);
```

This is my code. It creates user but assigns authenticated user role also by default . How can i achive my target?
I want
a) New role staff
b) staff is not an authenticated user or no permission of an authenticated user
Pls help me. I am using drupal 6

Comment: The authenticated user role just denotes that a user has an entry in the user table (i.e. is able to login to the site)...I can't imagine a scenario where that would be a problem, could you expand a bit?

Comment: My authenticated users are my assembly members, and i created a separated theme also for that user. But we have shopping cart in which everyone can purchase but we require them to register because of some tax exception cases.For this i created the users which are created from ubercart checkout page as "staff". Now i don't want any further permission other than accessing their own profile.

Answer (score 9):

I think you are using the autenticated user role for something specific. You should create a new role which is taking the rights of autenticated user. Once done, you can take away all rights from the autenticated user role.

To make things more clear:
You are using the *autenticated user* role for *assembly members*. You should create a new role *assembly members* which is taking the rights of *autenticated user*. Once done, you can take away all rights from the *autenticated user* role.