# How to create a role without some permissions an "Authenticated User" has?

Tags: 8, users

I have created a custom role. It automatically receives any permissions given to authenticated users. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

What I would like to achieve is:

Authenticated user: has permission to edit email address and password

Custom role: doesn't have permission to edit email address and password

Currently on my site, users all have the permission "Authenticated user". I would like some new users to have the "Custom role".

The answer to this question: [How can i create a user without role authenticated user role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/how-can-i-create-a-user-without-role-authenticated-user-role) suggests to instead edit the "Authenticated user role" and swap the "Custom role" to being the one with more permissions.

So instead I would have to have:

"Authenticated user": doesn't have permission to edit email address and password.

"Custom role": has permission to edit email address and password.

BUT if I do this then all of the current users will no longer be able to edit their email address and password, as they will still be "Authenticated Users", and updating each user to the new role would require entering their password (which I can't do).

Note: I would still like all users to be able to edit other fields such as "First Name".

Comment: The reason updating each user to the new role would require entering their password was actually a bug with the 'Password Policy' module. I edited the module code to fix this issue, which allowed me to change the role of all present users to a new custom role with more permissions than "Authenticated user", which I took some permissions away from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. The authenticated is the mimialist role with the lowest permissions.

You give it the Minimal permissions then make other roles with added permissions to the authenticated.